# Beamer.el not loaded

Tags: beamer, emacs, auctex

from what I have learnt from my research so far, auctex should load beamer.el automatically once a `*.tex` file with `\documentclass{beamer}` is loaded.
However, this is not the case here and I find the following error in `*messages*`:

```
File mode specification error: (file-error "Cannot open load file" "beamer")
```

As I have not found any usefull ideas so far what could be wrong, here two further pieces of information that could help to solve the problem.

First, I have the following in my `.emacs`:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (require 'beamer)
        (require 'reftex) 
))
```

Second, I use Ubuntu 12.04 and did a manual upgrade from Texlive 2009 to Texlive 2012. As I am not really sure, if my problem occurred already before I can't say if this latter might be the source of the problem.

Please ask for any further information that might help.

Thank you very much.

Comment: First: remove `(require 'beamer)`, this won't work.  Second: do you have the lines `(setq TeX-auto-save t) (setq TeX-parse-self t) (setq-default TeX-master nil)` in your `.emacs`, as described in [AUCTeX manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html)?

Comment: yes, all of the described are included (however, with a `'` before each bracket). Removing `(require 'beamer)` has the result that the error does not appear anymore in `*messages*`; however, beamer.el functionality is still missing then (which is my problem, obvisously).

Comment: Remove quotes before that lines and you're done.

Comment: Thanks alot, indeed that's it. What did the quote do? Is it commenting out the lines like `;`? Unfortunately I build my `.emacs` from copying pieces that I find on the internet, so I can't say why I had it quoted. (Finally: how do I close the question?)

Comment: No, quotes prevent evaluation of the following symbol, list, function, etc.  See [Quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Quoting.html#Quoting) on Emacs Lisp Reference Manual.

Answer (score 4):

To make the `beamer` style file work (like for all AUCTeX style files), you just need to add the following  your `.emacs`

```lisp
(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq-default TeX-master nil)
```

without quoting `setq` or `setq-default` functions.  The `(require 'beamer)` call is useless.

This is the complete working `.emacs`

```lisp
(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq-default TeX-master nil)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (require 'reftex)))
```